# How to replace a character in a string with a non ascii character in python?

Tags: python, string, non-ascii-characters

I want to replace the number sign (#) with a character similar to that called music sharp sign (♯). I tried the following line but didnt work.

```
res['n'].replace('#', '♯')
```

I also tried these and also didnt work fine.

```
res['n'].replace('#', u'♯')
res['n'].replace('#', '\xe2')
```

Anyone got any idea about the situation?

Comment: It "didnt work". What was the error? It works perfectly fine to me. What is `res`?

Comment: first one works for me.

Comment: Maybe you were expecting `replace()` to modify the string in place?  `replace()` doesn't do that; it creates a new string.  You would need to write `res['n'] = res['n'].replace('#', '♯')`.

Comment: ♯ == \xe2\x99\xaf, not only \xe2

Comment: Good point @ceremcem: Also, `'\xe2\x99\xaf'.decode('utf-8') == u'\u266f'`.

Comment: check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res="He##o"
res=res.replace("#","♯")
print res

o/t He♯♯o
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = ' '
re.sub(' ', '\x00', text)
```

Why not you use this?

Comment: Why do you think this is even vaguely relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Replace returns the changed string, strings cannot be changed themselves. Try

```
res['n'] = res['n'].replace('#', '♯')
```